# ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Import the excel file to dataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I have the problem with `dataGridView` - `Range`. I am trying to insert one `excel` file to the `dataGridView` in `Windows Form` but something is wrong.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fname);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[i + 1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
excelTable = createAnArray(rowCount, colCount);
for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
        {
            excelTable[i - 1, j - 1] = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
            // PROBLEM --->
            dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j - 1].Value = excelTable[i - 1, j - 1];
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j - 1].Value = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            excelTable[i - 1, j - 1] = "";
        }
    }
}
```

> Error:
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
>   Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Well, you have the code and you have the Excel file and you have the debugger... fire it up and att least find out which line it is and what the index is that is out of range.

Comment: I am sorry. i should write that this line is a problem:
dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j - 1].Value = excelTable[i - 1, j - 1];

Comment: Check the values of the indexes when the Exception occurs using the debugger, that will be the easiest way to find the problem.

Comment: The problem is when i=1 and j=1.
In this moment should be dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value but the code don't accept this. Why, i am not sure. It should.